How to click on datatable element using List<DataRow>
I am using Dart and Flutter on Windows.
I am using the Datatable class.
This class is using List<DataRow> and List<DataColumn>.
I want to click on a table element.
For now, I just want to open a popup.
Could you please advise how to implement the datatable click.
Thank You

Can't you use a GestureDetector?

If you just want a table with DataTable widget which enable you to click on cell content and a popup shows on, you can follow this pattern:
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: DataTable(
          columns: const [
            DataColumn(label: Text('Col 1')),
            DataColumn(label: Text('Col 2')),
          ],
          rows: [
            DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                        content: const Text('This is a popup'),
                        actions: [TextButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(), child: const Text('Close'))],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('Open popup'))),
              const DataCell(Text('Cell 2')),
            ])
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

This is a minimal example. If you expect more feel free to leave comment.
